# Python Selenium auto-test (How to get text of a column)

Tags: selenium, xpath

Using Xpath tool from chrome dev tools, I have been able to get xpath string and a td object. I 'm just wondering how do we find the value of text in a td object using selenium python web-drivers?

Comment: you can use text property of element for getting value

Comment: yes, thanks. I was lookng at a disabled section for text value. Sorry for asking such a silly question.

Comment: can give me one example what you want. Otherwise you can use get_attribute("innerHTML") method get inner text.

Answer (score 0):

for your case you can use .gettext() method of selenium.

Once I found that, the attribute within td which contains the text is changing and i was supposed to fetch the text in those attribute.
like

```html
<td class="table__cell" data-col-index="1">
<div class="ec-table__cell-content ">813.75</div>
</td>
<td class="table__cell" data-col-index="2">
<span class="ec-table__cell-content ">522.12</span>
</td>
```

So to get text within all td in a list, I used dynamic Xpath way:
By.xpath("//td[contains(@class,'table__cell')]/following::*").getText()

Answer (score 0):

Try to search by xpath. Relatively to some ID.

Example of:

```
id("body_content")/table/tbody/tr/td[3]
```

in this case will be shown exact elements of 3rd column only.